# Can you 3d model threaded objects for printing in blender?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

Is there a way to 3d model threads on a bolt with precise dimensions (i.e M7 x 1.25) that can than be printed?

Comment: Yes you can.  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237421/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-m6-screw/237423#237423

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45395/how-to-create-screw-thread-with-a-circular-profile https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads